# CSV and Dictionary Subsets

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm sure this is very basic but hopefully I can get a response. I've loaded the .csv file and now I'm trying to create a subset of this dictionary. So I want to create a smaller dictionary when the values in say col1=x and col4=y (both are strings). If they happen to not equal those particular strings, I want them removed from the dictionary. Is this possible???

```
import csv
input_file = csv.DictReader(open("CAGRF4742_SHSY_SNV.csv"))
```

Comment: Adding a simple example of your input and desired output would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

use the del

```
a = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
print a
# Output: {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
del a['b']
print a
# Output: {'a':1, 'c':3}
```